# Is there any function or dependency that can convert the month in a date to desired language in dataweave1 (mule3)?

Tags: date, mule, locale, dataweave, mule-el

I am working on a problem where date must be converted to the desired format. And if the format is yyyy/MMM/dd then the month should be converted to the language which is fetched from db.
eg. For 2021-01-12 the desired format is yyyy/MMM/dd and desired language is Spanish.

I have tried:

```
'2021-01-12' as :date{format :'yyyy-MM-dd', locale :'es'} as :string{format : 'yyyy/MMM/dd'}
```

As well as :

```
`2021-01-12' as :date{format :`yyyy-MM-dd`} as :string{format : `yyyy/MMM/dd' ,locale :'es'}
```

The output must be 2021/ene/12 but everytime I am getting is 2021/Jan/12.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug. It works with the full month name format `MMMM`. I suggest create a function in DataWeave to do the translations manually, or alternatively try to implement it in a flow with MEL functions, Groovy scripts or Java and call the flow from DataWeave with [lookup()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-reference-documentation#expressions-that-call-external-flows).

Example of using MMMM:

```
"2021-01-12" 
    as :date{format : "yyyy-MM-dd"} 
    as :string {format: "dd, MMMM, yyyy", locale: "ES"}
```

Output:

```
"12, enero, 2021"
```

DataWeave 2/Mule 4 seems to handle the same case better:

```
"2021-01-12" 
    as Date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"} 
    as String {format: "yyyy/MMM/dd", locale: "ES"}
```

Output:

```
"2021/ene./12"
```

Comment: So I must use locale in string or date?

Comment: When converting to string. You would use it in Date if you need to parse a string.

Comment: I expanded my answer and added examples.